# Is there an efficient way to select 5 regions of a tensor in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

For example, given a tensor m which its shape is [28, 28].

I want to randomly select five regions with the tensor, the shape of each region is [3, 3].

Then, I want to modify the values of these regions.

Answer (score 0):

One sulution would be random extraction inside a loop:

```
import random
tensor = tf.ones(shape=(28,28))
desired_shape = (3,3)
dim1 = random.randint(0,tensor.shape[0] - desired_shape[0])
dim2 = random.randint(0,tensor.shape[1] - desired_shape[1])
extracted_tensor = tensor[dim1:dim1+desired_shape[0]][:,dim2 + desired_shape[1]]
```

First import the random module and create a (or use your) tensor. Set your desired_shape.
Then create two random variables, one for each dimension and extract the tensor via sublisting.

But, keep in mind, that you cannot assign values to a tensor in tensorflow as this [thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33131) says.

To solve this, first convert it to a numpy array, change the values and convert it to a tensor again, so this would be a solution for your issue.

```
np_arr = tensor.numpy()
for i in range(5):
    dim1 = random.randint(0,tensor.shape[0] - desired_shape[0])
    dim2 = random.randint(0,tensor.shape[1] - desired_shape[1])
    np_arr[dim1:dim1+desired_shape[0]][:,dim2 + desired_shape[1]] = [1,2,3] # any value

new_tens = tf.convert_to_tensor(np_arr)
```